# SDL_Event.type always empty after polling

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a general function that is supposed to handle any event in the SDL event queue. So far, the function looks like this:

```
int eventhandler(void* args){
  cout << "Eventhandler started.\n";
  while (!quit){
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
      cout << "Got event to handle: " << event.type << "\n";
      switch (event.type){
        SDL_KEYDOWN:
          keyDownHandler(event.key.keysym.sym);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I test the function, I get a whole bunch of events but *none* of them seem to have a type. It doesn't even print 0 or anything — just nothing. The output when pressing any key looks like this:

```
Got event to handle:
```

And nothing else. Any tutorial and the SDL docs say that I should handle events like this, but it isn't working. Anybody else have this problem or a solution?

By the way, the eventhandler runs in an SDL_Thread, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: `SDL_KEYDOWN:` should be `case SDL_KEYDOWN:`.

Comment: @gf: You're right, thanks. Oddly enough that solved it too. The event.type is still empty but *somehow* it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not compiling through MS Visual C++, but a word of caution on the use of "event". It's actually a keyword in VC++, and I'd change it to "e" or what ever, for the sake of compatibility. You might one day wish to use VC++, or someone else might want to view your work through it. It's a very commonly used compiler after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That nothing happens is a result of the missing `case` in front of `SDL_KEYDOWN`.
With `case` missing the compiler sees a jump label which you would use for e.g. `goto SDL_KEYDOWN;`, which results in the `default` label being the only label in the `switch` statement.

I don't see why `event.type` doesn't get output though unless you set some stream-flags somewhere.
`event.type` is an `Uint8` which SDL just typedefs from integral types, so it should be handled like one. Like any integral type it also can't be *"empty"*, but the output for it can be.